# Pygame window freezes when mouse doesn't move

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game in which you are nyan cat and you have to dodge asteroids in space (don't ask). The game runs very well I have even implemented a score system. But for some reason whenever I stop moving my cursor in the pygame window (i am not moving my mouse left and right in the game window) it will freeze and get really laggy. Does anyone know whats going on!? HELP! - PLEASE!!

Here is an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJJDxZE_kbU

Code:

```
# Import modules and initialize
import pygame as p
import sys
import random
p.init()
# Define variables
player_movement = 0
GRAVITY = 0.25
asteroid_height = [300, 100, 400, 200]
score = 0
high_score = 0
game_font = p.font.Font('fonts/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf',20)
game_active = True
# Make some functions
def create_asteroid():
    random_asteroid_pos = random.choice(asteroid_height)
    new_asteroid = asteroid_surface.get_rect(midtop = (650, random_asteroid_pos))
    return new_asteroid
def move(asteroids):
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        asteroid.centerx -= 5
    return asteroids
def draw(asteroids):
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        sc.blit(asteroid_surface, asteroid)
def collision(asteroids):
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        if player_rect.colliderect(asteroid):
            hit_sound.play()
            return False
        if player_rect.top <= -100 or player_rect.bottom >= 750:
            return False
    return True
def display_score(game_state):
    if game_state == 'in_game':
        score_surface = game_font.render(f'Score: {int(score)}',True, (255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (110, 30))
        sc.blit(score_surface, score_rect)
    elif game_state == 'game_over':
        high_score_surface = game_font.render(f'High Score: {int(high_score)}',True, (255,255,255))
        high_score_rect = high_score_surface.get_rect(center = (320, 370))
        sc.blit(high_score_surface, high_score_rect)
def update_score(score, high_score):
    if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
    return high_score
# Make a screen
sc = p.display.set_mode((700, 700))
# Make a backround
bg = p.image.load('images/backround.png')
bg = p.transform.scale2x(bg)
# Import character
ship = p.image.load('images/ship.png').convert()
# Import asteroid
asteroid_surface = p.image.load('images/asteroid.png').convert()
# Asteroid logic
asteroid_list = []
SPAWN = p.USEREVENT
p.time.set_timer(SPAWN, 2500)
# Hitbox variables
player_rect = ship.get_rect(center = (100, 350))
# Sound FX
jump_sound = p.mixer.Sound('sound/jump.wav')
hit_sound = p.mixer.Sound('sound/impact.wav')
# Begin code logic
while True:
    # Make the game exit cleanly
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            p.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == p.K_SPACE and game_active:
                player_movement = 0
                player_movement -= 6
                jump_sound.play()
            if event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_SPACE and game_active == False:
                    game_active = True
                    asteroid_list.clear()
                    player_movement = 0
                    score = 0
                    player_rect.center = (100, 350)
        if event.type == SPAWN:
            asteroid_list.append(create_asteroid())
        sc.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        if game_active:
            player_movement += GRAVITY
            player_rect.centery += player_movement
            # Draw asteroids and player
            sc.blit(ship,player_rect)
            asteroid_list = move(asteroid_list)
            draw(asteroid_list)
            game_active = collision(asteroid_list)
            # Score system
            score += 0.01
            display_score('in_game')
            # Game info
            info_surface = game_font.render('SPACE to move!',True, (255,255,255))
            info_rect = info_surface.get_rect(center = (550, 30))
            sc.blit(info_surface, info_rect)
        else:
            high_score = update_score(score, high_score)
            display_score('game_over')
            # Make the main menu/game over screen
            game_over_surface = game_font.render('Game Over!',True, (255,255,255))
            game_over_rect = game_over_surface.get_rect(center = (320, 330))
            sc.blit(game_over_surface, game_over_rect)
            game_over_surface1 = game_font.render('SPACE to play again!',True, (255,255,255))
            game_over_rect1 = game_over_surface1.get_rect(center = (320, 350))
            sc.blit(game_over_surface1, game_over_rect1)
        p.display.update()
```

Comment: You have to add the relevant code to the question. How can one help you find the bug in your code without seeing it?

Comment: Very likely the issue is an related to the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You need to draw the scene in the application loop instead of the event loop.

Comment: NateDogg like @Rabbid76 said, you have to draw everything outside of the event loop

Comment: So I have a game loop that draws the characters and the asteroids only if you are not collision with an asteroid. Should I make a while loop and continuously draw the background? I just have the background run in the game loop.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! It's buttery smooth now. :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You must drew the scene in the application loop instead of the event loop:

```py
while True:
    # Make the game exit cleanly
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            p.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == p.K_SPACE and game_active:
                player_movement = 0
                player_movement -= 6
                jump_sound.play()
            if event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_SPACE and game_active == False:
                    game_active = True
                    asteroid_list.clear()
                    player_movement = 0
                    score = 0
                    player_rect.center = (100, 350)
        if event.type == SPAWN:
            asteroid_list.append(create_asteroid())

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    sc.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if game_active:
        player_movement += GRAVITY
        player_rect.centery += player_movement
        # Draw asteroids and player
        sc.blit(ship,player_rect)
        asteroid_list = move(asteroid_list)
        draw(asteroid_list)
        game_active = collision(asteroid_list)
        # Score system
        score += 0.01
        display_score('in_game')
        # Game info
        info_surface = game_font.render('SPACE to move!',True, (255,255,255))
        info_rect = info_surface.get_rect(center = (550, 30))
        sc.blit(info_surface, info_rect)
    else:
        high_score = update_score(score, high_score)
        display_score('game_over')
        # Make the main menu/game over screen
        game_over_surface = game_font.render('Game Over!',True, (255,255,255))
        game_over_rect = game_over_surface.get_rect(center = (320, 330))
        sc.blit(game_over_surface, game_over_rect)
        game_over_surface1 = game_font.render('SPACE to play again!',True, (255,255,255))
        game_over_rect1 = game_over_surface1.get_rect(center = (320, 350))
        sc.blit(game_over_surface1, game_over_rect1)
    p.display.update()
```